# What would be the best way to store site preferences?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a massive revamp of my CMS, and was wondering, what would be the best way to store site preferences...

Currently my pereference setup is within database, full of structure fields (each representing it's own preference), but only id 1 is used. And... I somehow don't like this solution. Now I'm thinking of setting preferences within php file, but then there are problems with editing preferences. Well, not problems, but using files as storage is just bad in my opinion.

With site preferences I mean "Site title", "Site slogan", "Meta keywords", "Meta description" etc., not database info or other totally static values.

So... Are there any other solutions you guys could share?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are these preferences subject of frequent changes or more of a static nature?

Comment: They'll be changed once in a while. But not by developer (me), but by user through website form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no easy answer to this question.  As @Redlab asked, are the preferences frequently changing?  If so, then the DB seems like the "better" alternative.  But there is a lot more to it than that...

Are there a lot of these preferences?  If so, then storing it in the filesystem may make sense with namespaced files and hiearchial storage.  So for example:

In site.php

```
return array(
    'title' => 'This is my page title',
    'meta' => array(
        'description' => 'My Meta Description',
        'keywords' => 'key1, key2, key3',
    ),
);
```

Basically, create a file for each "namespace" to group things together.

The advantage to doing it this way is performance and managability.  You can lazy-load the config on a per-namespace basis as needed.  You could mimic the effect in the database by adding a field called namespace, and then lazy-loading those fields, but it's going to be significantly slower since every access requires a query.  If you have a lot of settings, then loading it from the db on every page hit (even once) is not going to be optimal either...

What I do is use dot notation.  So from the above example, to get the meta keywords would be `site.meta.keywords`.  It's actually reasonably easy to do:

```
class Config {
    protected $data = array();

    public function get($name, $default = null) {
        $parts = explode('.', $name);
        $ns = array_shift($parts);
        if (!isset($this->data[$ns])) {
            $this->loadNS($ns);
        }
        $search = $this->data[$ns];
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (is_array($search) && isset($search[$part])) {
                $search = $search[$part];
            } else {
                return $default;
            }
        }
        return $search;
    }

    protected loadNS($name) {
        $path = PATH_TO_CONFIG . $name . '.php';
        if (is_file($path)) {
            $this->data[$name] = include($path);
        } else {
            $this->data[$name] = array();
        }
    }
}
```

You can add a set and a save method just as easy.

To save the files:

```
public function saveToFile($ns) {
    if (!isset($this->data[$ns])) {
        $this->loadNS($ns);
    }
    $out = '<?php return '.var_export($this->data[$ns], true).';';
    $path = PATH_TO_CONFIG . $ns . '.php'
    file_put_contents($path, $out);
}
```

What results is a very easy to maintain (since it's only ever writing to the filesystem) and easy to modify by hand (since it's all just php code) system for storing and retrieving information.

And best of all, since it can take advantage of opcode caches, it's VERY efficient and won't slow your page down at all...

Comment: Hmm... This looks interesting. Used pretty similar system for my languages. With static value sitting in file and written there by var_export etc.

I guess, I'll use your method! :) Thanks!

Comment: I do the same thing.  It's used for translations and configuration (everything from DB connections on up).  It makes sense (IMHO) if your program is highly modular, where you can "enable" or "disable" modules (and hence then not have to load that part of the language/config system on each page load)...

Answer (score 1):

I like CodeIgniter's approach to site config. Storing all config files in a common folder, such as `/config` and placing each config item to a `$config` array, like so:

```
<?php

    $config['base_url'] = "http://foo.bar/baz";
    $config['language'] = "english";
    $config['charset']  = "UTF-8";
    // ...
```

Later, these files could then be auto-loaded and referenced using some global method, for example:

```
get_config_item("base_url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current set up, using a database, is ideal in my opinion. Take a look at how WordPress stores this kind of site preference -- they do it in the DB. Config belongs in a static config file, Preferences in the DB.